# Is it safe to declare Parse app id and server url on client side JS?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

For example is it safe to put this in my .js file that's client side.

```
Parse.initialize("myAppId");
Parse.serverURL = 'https://0fc98698cc.ngrok.io/1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as [the docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) say, it is safe to use the `YOUR_APP_ID`, `YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY` and `YOUR_PARSE_SERVER` URL on the client side, but **NOT** the `YOUR_MASTERKEY`.

> ```
> Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY", "YOUR_MASTERKEY");
> //javascriptKey is required only if you have it on server.
>
> Parse.serverURL = 'http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is totally safe to expose your `APP_ID` and `SERVER_URL`. App ID only identify your parse applications if you are hosting more than one parse app on your node process. For instance, if you are mounting more than 1 parse server to an express application, you use different app ids and mounting points.